# New value added to Java Enum not available during debug

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

I am having the following problem:

I have an Enum that was originally declared with 5 elements.

```
public enum GraphFormat {
  DOT,
  GML,
  PUML,
  JSON,
  NEO4J,
  TEXT {
    @Override
    public String getFileExtension() {
      return ".txt";
    }
  };
```

Now I need to add an additional element to it (NEO4J). When I run my code or try to debug it I am getting an exception because the value can't be found in the enum. 
[image: Variables at debug time]
I am using IntelliJ as my IDE, and have cleaned the cache, force a rebuild, etc.. and nothing happens. When I look at the .class file created on my target folder, it also has the new element.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue ?

Comment: What folder is configured in `Project Structure->Modules->Paths->Output path`? Sometimes Intellij has `out` there instead of `target` (depending on how the project was created, I believe). And if you used maven or gradle to rebuild then the .class file in `target` might be up to date but not the one in `out`.

Comment: The few times this has happened to me, it was because I just forgot to relaunch the app I was debugging :|

Comment: @binotemary - I just checked the project output path and is pointing to the output folders. Note that if I open the .class file in the output folders it has the new element. It just looks like the debugger is running a byte code from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem and want to share here what was causing it. My code was actually for a Maven plug-in which I was pointing to another project of mine to run it as a goal. However the pom.xml of my target test project was pointing to the original version of the plug-in instead of the one I am working on, and that version of course is outdated and does not include the new value. Thank you.